# ERROR "Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts."

Tags: c#, mysql

i am newbie in c#. I want to connect to my database. If i do this with the adress " localhost" it is working fine. If i use my Webserver IP it doesn't work and the Error

> Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.

What is my Problem?

```
namespace MySqlCRUD
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    String connectionString = "server=84.200.7.136;uid=root;" +
    "pwd=;database=bookdb;";


    int AcapWatchID = 0;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            mysqlCon.Open();
            MySqlCommand mySqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("BookAddOrEdit",mysqlCon);
            mySqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_AcapWatchID", AcapWatchID);
            mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_Artist", txtArtist.Text.Trim());
            mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_Albumname", txtAlbumname.Text.Trim());
            mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_Download1", txtDownload1.Text.Trim());
            mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_Download2", txtDownload2.Text.Trim());
            mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_Verlinkt",  txtVerlinkt.Text.Trim());
            mySqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("[ACAPWatch] Album wurde erfolgreich hinzugefügt!");
            Clear();
            GridFill();
        }
    }

    void GridFill()
    {
        using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            mysqlCon.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new MySqlDataAdapter("BookViewAll",mysqlCon);
            sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            DataTable dtblBook = new DataTable();
            sqlDa.Fill(dtblBook);
            dgvBook.DataSource = dtblBook;
            dgvBook.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        }
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clear();
        GridFill();
    }

    void Clear()
    {
        txtArtist.Text = txtAlbumname.Text = txtDownload1.Text = txtDownload2.Text = txtVerlinkt.Text = txtSearch.Text = "";
        AcapWatchID = 0;
        btnSave.Text = "Speichern";
        btnDelete.Enabled = false;
    }

    private void dgvBook_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvBook.CurrentRow.Index != -1)
        {
            txtArtist.Text = dgvBook.CurrentRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            txtAlbumname.Text = dgvBook.CurrentRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            txtDownload1.Text = dgvBook.CurrentRow.Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            txtDownload2.Text = dgvBook.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value.ToString();
            txtVerlinkt.Text = dgvBook.CurrentRow.Cells[5].Value.ToString();
            AcapWatchID = Convert.ToInt32(dgvBook.CurrentRow.Cells[0].Value.ToString());
            btnSave.Text = "Löschen";
            btnDelete.Enabled = Enabled;
        }
    }

    private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            mysqlCon.Open();
            MySqlDataAdapter sqlDa = new MySqlDataAdapter("BookSearchByValue", mysqlCon);
            sqlDa.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            sqlDa.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("_SearchValue",txtSearch.Text);
            DataTable dtblBook = new DataTable();
            sqlDa.Fill(dtblBook);
            dgvBook.DataSource = dtblBook;
            dgvBook.Columns[0].Visible = false;
        }
    }

    private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Clear();
    }

    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        using (MySqlConnection mysqlCon = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            mysqlCon.Open();
            MySqlCommand mySqlCmd = new MySqlCommand("BookDeleteByID", mysqlCon);
            mySqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            mySqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("_AcapWatchID", AcapWatchID);
            mySqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            MessageBox.Show("[ACAPWatch!] Album wurde aus der Datenbank entfernt!");
            Clear();
            GridFill();
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Is your MySQL running on same server as WebServer?

Comment: If it is, is it on the default port (3306)? Does your WebServers firewall allow traffic on MySQL's port?

Comment: Connector dot net says *any of the specified MySQL hosts* because it has failover stuff built in. In your case it just means *the MySQL host.*, so don't let that confuse you. Please [edit] your question to tell us whether you can connect from to your MySQL server from a client program (like HeidiSQL or something) running on your Windows machine to your web server's MySQL server. Some web hosting services block access to MySQL from outside their own machines.

Comment: You are including a password in the actual connection string, I presume?

Answer (score 0):

Is your MySQL running on same server as WebServer? 
Yes, running on the Same Server.

If it is, is it on the default port (3306)? Does your WebServers firewall allow traffic on MySQL's port?

Yes, run on default Port and the firewall allow trafic on this Port ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have just tried to connect using your connection string and got a different error (rejected because of missing password), which is what I would expect.
It is not generally a good idea when posting questions to include real Connection strings (assuming the IP address etc. you gave is real).  You are exposing your database to attack!